# In SQL Server is there a way I can define a computed column to be equal to the ASCII value of the first character of one of the columns?

Tags: sql-server

I have a simple table that contains words:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Word] (
    [WordId]       VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
    [CategoryId]   INT          DEFAULT ((1)) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([WordId] ASC),
);
```

Is it possible to create a new column that automatically holds the ASCII value of the first character of WordId that I could access with a SELECT? I am not very sure about SQL but I read about Computed Columns and also I wonder if I can populate the default value of a column based on the value of another column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The T-SQL `ASCII` function will get you the ASCII code of the first character of a character expression. Using that function, you can define your computed column (which I'm naming "Ascii") like this:

```
[Ascii] as (ASCII([WordId]))
```

The complete table definition would become:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Word] (
    [WordId]       VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
    [CategoryId]   INT          DEFAULT ((1)) NOT NULL,
    [Ascii]        as (ASCII([WordId])),
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([WordId] ASC),
);
```

Example result:

```
INSERT INTO [Word] ([WordId], [CategoryId]) SELECT 'Testing', 1
```

The record created by that insert would have a value in the `Ascii` column of 84.

Comment: Yep, that is correct. I'll edit the answer. Thanks @MartinSmith.